# Rails: I want to add index to the resource :symbol route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

Users have subscriptions to feeds but when I change (as suggested elsewhere on stackO)

```
resource :subscriptions
```

to

```
resources: subscriptions
```

it breaks some ajax functionality I already have implemented regarding destroy.

I want to be able to link to /subscriptions/ and have users be able to view all of their subscriptions.  The problem is that currently it's bringing me to subscriptions#show when I really want #index.

How should I do this?

Here's my AJAX:

```
<div id="subscribe" class="shadow">
<% if session[:read_random]
    unless is_subscribed?(session[:read_random].last)%>
            <%= link_to 'Subscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :post, remote: :true %>

    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :delete, remote: :true %>

<%  end
   end %>
</div>
```

Here's my destroy method

```
def destroy

      if params[:feed_id]
          #this is the ajax call
          @subscription = Subscription.find_by_user_id_and_feed_id(session[:user_id], params[:feed_id])
      else
          #this is the index destroy call (unsubscribe)
          @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
      end
  @subscription.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to request.referer }
    format.js
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: The difference it looks like in the break of my ajax functionality is that no route matches [DELETE] "/subscriptions" once I add the 's' to 'resource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the default resourceful routes for a plural resource, the proper destroy route would be `subscription_path(id), method: :delete`.  Note that subscription is singular.  For these routes, the destroy path is generally identical to the show and update path, with the exception of http method used.